# Program to display character only displays '?' in java

Tags: java, character

Wrote a program to display all that character. But the output only display the ? character. I am a total newbie, please help.

```
public class charSheet {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        char c;

        for(int i = 0; i < 65536; i++){
            c = (char) i;
            System.out.println(i + "---" + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output(only a part):
57987---?
57988---?
57989---?
57990---?
57991---?
57992---?

Comment: The problem is your terminal, which isn't configured to display those characters properly.

Comment: What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Check for the output. You just see last part of your output and your output is getting scrolled up. Change your loop if you are interested to see something, start from 33 instead of 0 and loop till 122 instead of huge number 65536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try printing it till 100, it does prints some characters, you probably are using command prompt which does not supports much characters, try using some IDE such as Eclipse, i think you will get better results.

Comment: I am using eclipse Sarthak.

Comment: check this link out maybe there is some problem in your default encoding:

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

Range of characters are from 0 - 255. 
Everything after that is therefore irrelevant.